# How to read a page's "Shortcodes" from the Template File?

Tags: pages, shortcode, templates

Lets say i have a Page, and it contains some `shortcodes` like:

```
[myshortcode foo="bar" bar="bing"]
[anothershortcode foo="bing" bing="bar"]
```

Then how do i read those from my custom Template File, to manipulate please?

Comment: I don't really get your question, sorry. Is that what you're looking for? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode or this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

Answer (score 2):

### Parsing shortcodes from strings

WordPress parses and replaces shortcodes from a piece of content via the `do_shortcode` function. This function, in turn, calls `get_shortcode_regex`, which returns the regular expression for matching shortcodes in a string.

Using this function, we can get a list of all shortcodes ourselves:

```
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
preg_match_all( "/$pattern/s", $content, $matches );
print_r( $matches );
```

[`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) puts all matches in `$content` for our regular expression in `$matches`. `$matches` will then contain a two-dimensional array. For a string like this, for example:

```
[first-shortcode no-content="true"]
This is shortcode testing content.
[sample-shortcode title="Testing"]This is a test[/sample-shortcode]
```

(assuming the shortcodes `first-shortcode` and `sample-shortcode` exist), `print_r( $matches );` would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [first-shortcode no-content="true"]
            [2] => [sample-shortcode title="Testing"]This is a test[/sample-shortcode]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => first-shortcode
            [1] => sample-shortcode
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  no-content="true"
            [1] =>  title="Testing"
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => This is a test
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )
)
```

As you can see, for all matches (shortcodes), there is an entry in each of the seven arrays at the first level. `$matches[0]` contains the entire shortcode, `$matches[2]` contains the shortcode name, `$matches[3]` the attributes string and `$matches[5]` the shortcode content.

I'm not sure what part you wish to manipulate, so I won't go into detail on that. You can pass the flag `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` to `preg_match_all` in the `$flags`-parameter; this will make sure the offset at which a match (shortcode) occurs in the string is stored as well.

### Getting the content of a page template

To get the content of a template file (which could be a page template) of the current theme, you can simply use [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template), which returns the path to a template file, after which you can get its contents by using an output buffer.

```
ob_start();
locate_template( 'tpl-my-page-template.php', true );
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but the first part of my answer is at least part of what you need :-).